# Assertion for attributes with syntax: "string || string || string....." in XSD 1.1

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following really short XML file:

```
<objective name="WriteYourPaper">
    <task task="TalkToSupervisor" />
    <task task="AcceptPaperNegatively || AcceptPaperPositively" />
    <task task="TalkToSupervisor || AcceptPaperNegatively || AcceptPaperPositively"" />
</objective>
```

There can be as many "task" elements as I want inside the objective element. So I think this is a good way to define it in my XSD:

```
<xs:element name="objective " type="objectiveType"/>

<xs:complexType name="objectiveType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="taskType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="task " type="taskType"/>

<xs:complexType name="taskType">
    <xs:attribute name="task" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

The question is the following: as you can see in my example there is the possibility to insert in the "task" attribute a string which has to adhere to special restrictions and I need a special assertation for that. It can be a simple string "string" or a sequence of strings separated by "*blankSpaces* || *blankSpaces* ". May you please help me defining the assertation and telling me where I should place it? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Unfortunately I just realized that I need a further restriction. Indeed the strings that are in the "task" elements have to follow certain criteria. My XML has a definition of some "actions" and "staticActions" like the following:

```
<staticAction name="Study" >
    ...
</staticAction>

<action name="TalkToSupervisor" dialog="DialogWithSupervisor" actor="Supervisor">
    ...
</action>
```

In that "task" attribute I need to check that the syntax "name (*spaces*) || (*spaces*) name (*spaces*) || ..." is followed where each *name* is a name of an Action or a StaticAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSD has the concept of a list type, which allows you to describe an attribute as containing a sequence of strings, each of which must conform to the same atomic type. Unfortunately, though, list types always correspond to whitespace-separated lists of strings. If you want to choose a different separator, then XSD has no built-in support for the concept. How much do you really need the separators?

It's not clear from your question whether the set of task names (e.g. "TalkToSupervisor") is something you want to define in the schema, or whether it should be open-ended. Assuming it's an open-ended list (any sequence of letters allowed), you can define your ||-separated attribute type using a pattern, e.g.

```
<xs:simpleType name="taskListType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="\s+([A-Za-z]+\s+\|\|\s+)*[A-Za-z]+\s+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But I would prefer to go for space-separated lists and use an XSD list type.

Comment: I am sorry, you just made me realize that I need a further restriction.. I just edited the question. My apologies for the inattention.

Comment: This refinement of the requirement makes it even more desirable to use a standard XSD list type (whitespace-separated) because then you can enforce the constraints using key/keyref.

Comment: may you kindly edit your answer and show me how to do it? I am a newbie in this field and it doesn't sound that easy at my ears. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please raise a new question. Supplementary questions don't work well on SO.